# Installing plugin to application running on Linux SUSE

Tags: linux, software-installation, compatibility

I have an application running on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. A plugin is available which is installed by running an installation program (which unpacks, creates directories and registry entries etc. etc.).

The version of the plugin and the version of the application running on the server must be the same. The version of the plugin at my disposal is not the same as the version of the application running on the server.

The problem is that the installation program checks the version of the plugin.

Does anybody have an idea what I could do? Ideally I would be able to alter the installation program so that it does not perform the check, but I have no idea how to or if it is even possible.

Please note: I have NO idea about Linux.

Of course using the same version would be preferable, but I know that technically it is possible to use different versions. The problem I have is that I cannot get hold of the proper plugin version nor change the version of the application to match the plugin. Hence, I am looking for a work-around.

Comment: I think you can only hope to get guidance here by providing more details about what the plugin and application are.  Do they have names? What extension does the installation script have?

Comment: Note that Linux does not have a registry like Windows does.

Comment: Thankx for ur comments. I do not have access to the application, since it has been installed with AWS for me. How do I find out what 'extension' the installtions script has? I have The installation script at my disposal and it is tiny (just 19 KB).

Comment: Can you open the script with an editor (such as `vi` or `nano`) and do you see Latin characters or garbage? Do you have the rights to paste the contents of the script publicly? If so, can you post it somewhere?

Comment: Additional info: I have a second server where a second installation of a similar application is running (which is not usefull to me though) where the plugin has been installed (the plugin is exactly the same as the one I try to install). I copied the entire file structure underneath directory 'plugins' from that second installation to the first with the remote hope that it would work. Of course it did not :(

Comment: Link to the script file:  https://app.box.com/s/rg6pj8za2b3e10a2bwzh

Comment: No ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

One work-around that goes a long way around the problem is to install a virtual machine of the compatible version of SUSE that the plugin needs. Install the program and the plugin in the virtual machine. Then whenever you need to run this program with that plugin, you boot up the virtual machine and run it from there. Not an elegant solution, though.

Comment: Since it is running with AWS this solution will not be possible, right???